# Lost our Visualforce Page for Apex Controller to send SMS via Twilio

Tags: visualforce

At some point we lost the Vf page and ability to send SMS messages using the Apex below and I'm having problems re-creating a Vf page. Can you help?

It looks like the Vf page was very simple and should:

- look up Contacts who are tagged as a TwilioRegisteredUser (see query in  GetPersonList method)
- Recognize MobilePhone
- Have a text area for the message
- Have a button to send message

Here's the Apex class:

```
public with sharing class TwilioCloudCommunicationClass { 


// Public Properties  
public String SelectedMobileNumber{get;set;}  
public String OtherMobileNumber{get;set;}  
public String textMessage{get;set;}  

// Default construtor  
public TwilioCloudCommunicationClass()  
{  
    SelectedMobileNumber  = '' ;  
    OtherMobileNumber = '' ;  
}  

Public List<SelectOption> getPersonList()
{  
    Try{  
        List<SelectOption> localList = new List<SelectOption>();  
        localList.add(new SelectOption('' , '--Select--'));  
        for(contact cont : [select Name,MobilePhone from contact where TwilioRegisteredUser__c = true ])  
        {  
            localList.add(new SelectOption(cont.MobilePhone , cont.Name));            
        }        
        localList.add(new SelectOption('other' , 'Other'));  
        return localList ;  
    }  
    catch(Exception e)  
    {  
        ApexPages.addMessages(e);        
        return null;  
    }  
}  

public void SendSMS()  
{  
    Try{        
        SelectedMobileNumber = (SelectedMobileNumber == '')? OtherMobileNumber:SelectedMobileNumber ;  
        if(SelectedMobileNumber != '')  
        {  
            List<TwilioConfig__c> AdminInfo = TwilioConfig__c.getall().values();
            String ACCOUNT_SID = '';  
            String AUTH_TOKEN  = '' ;              
            String SenderMobileNumber = '' ;  
            // Informaton getting from custom setting  
            if(AdminInfo.size()>0)  
            {            
                ACCOUNT_SID             = AdminInfo[0].AccountSid__c;  
                AUTH_TOKEN              = AdminInfo[0].AuthToken__c;                  
                SenderMobileNumber      = AdminInfo[0].Admin_Mobile_Number__c;      
            }              
            TwilioRestClient client = new TwilioRestClient(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN);  

            Map<String, String> properties = new Map<String, String> { 
                        'To'  => SelectedMobileNumber , 
                        'From' => SenderMobileNumber, 
                        'Body' => textMessage   
                };  
            TwilioSMS message = client.getAccount().getSmsMessages().create(properties);  
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.INFO, 'Message has been sent'));  
        }  
        else  
        {  
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.Error, 'Please provide valid Mobile Number '));  
        }  
    }catch(Exception e )  
    {  
        ApexPages.addMessages(e);        
        return ;  
    }    
}  

}
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Always happy to give some Twilio love here...

This seems to work for me, though I don't have Twilio installed in my org:

```
<apex:page controller="TwilioCloudCommunicationClass" cache="false">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:actionFunction name="RefreshNumber" rerender="sms" >
              <apex:param name="firstParam" assignTo="{!SelectedMobileNumber}" value="" />
        </apex:actionFunction>
        <apex:pageBlock>
            <apex:pageBlockButtons>
                <apex:commandButton action="{!SendSMS}" value="Send SMS"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:pageBlockSection id="sms">
                <apex:outputLabel>Contact to Text</apex:outputLabel>
                <apex:selectList size="1" onchange="RefreshNumber(this.value)">
                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!PersonList}"/>
                </apex:selectList>
                <apex:outputLabel>Selected Number</apex:outputLabel>
                <apex:inputText value="{!SelectedMobileNumber}"/>
                <apex:outputLabel>Use Other Number</apex:outputLabel>
                <apex:inputText value="{!OtherMobileNumber}"/>
                <apex:outputLabel>Message to Send</apex:outputLabel>
                <apex:inputTextarea value="{!textMessage}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Thank you so much - looks/works better than screenshot of their original!

Comment: As nice as we got the form and button to look on our page, we'd like to automate the sending of SMS messages using workflows. What' approach should I take to pull in an Id for a class enrollment, phone number to send text to, Name, and class date - all from custom objects (we do not use any of the Sf standard objects for this (NPO only uses them for donations and Volunteers).

I appreciate your input.

Comment: I would probably look at some form of queueable job, or maybe create an invocable class you can call from Process Builder?