# Twilio SMS integration returns Schema Validation Warning in Twilio debug

Tags: apex, twilio

I've been following this [SmsToLead](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2012/04/sms-to-lead-with-the-twilio-library-for-salesforce.html) procedure and am stuck getting SMS messages into Salesforce. The Twilio debug console reports a Schema Validation Warning and this error:

> cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'html'.

Here's more info on this error:

> Warning - 12200
>
> Schema validation warning
>
> The provided XML does not conform to the Twilio Markup XML schema.
>   Please refer to the specific error and correct the problem. Possible
>   Causes
>
> misspelled verbs incorrect case for verbs misspelled or unknown
>   attributes unknown or unexpected nested elements.

Also, a post using curl returns error code 503/Forbidden so the apex isn't even getting executed. Not sure how else to troubleshoot beyond the re-re-rechecking of settings (done). Could a spec have have changed since this was put out there?

I've created a site (home page is InMaintenance or Exception - same result) and have authorized the controller class in Public Settings.

Here is the controller class:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/whwSMS/*')
global class SmsToLead {

    static TwilioAccount account = TwilioAPI.getDefaultAccount();

    @future(callout=true)
    public static void reply(String fromNumber, String toNumber, String message) {
        Map<String, String> params = new Map<String, String>{
          'From' => fromNumber, 
          'To' => toNumber, 
          'Body' => message
        };
        System.debug('Twilio account info: ' + account);

        TwilioSms sms = account.getSmsMessages().create(params);
        System.debug('Sent SMS SID: '+sms.getSid());
    }

    @HttpPost
    global static void incomingSMS() {
        // This will error out with System.LimitException if we would exceed 
        // our daily email limit
        Messaging.reserveSingleEmailCapacity(1);

        String expectedSignature = RestContext.request.headers.get('X-Twilio-Signature');
        String url = 'https://' + RestContext.request.headers.get('Host') + '/services/apexrest' + RestContext.request.requestURI;
        Map <String, String> params = RestContext.request.params;

        // Validate signature
        if (!TwilioAPI.getDefaultClient().validateRequest(expectedSignature, url, params)) {
            RestContext.response.statusCode = 403;
            RestContext.response.responseBody = Blob.valueOf('Failure! Rcvd '+expectedSignature+'\nURL '+url/*+'\nHeaders'+RestContext.request.headers*/);
            return;
        }

        // Twilio likes to see something in the response body, otherwise it reports
        // a 502 error in https://www.twilio.com/user/account/log/notifications
        RestContext.response.responseBody = Blob.valueOf('ok');

        // Extract useful fields from the incoming SMS
        String leadNumber     = params.get('From');
        String campaignNumber = params.get('To');
        String leadEmail      = params.get('Body');

        // Try to find a matching Campaign
        Campaign campaign = null;
        try {
            campaign = [SELECT Id, Name, NumberSent FROM Campaign WHERE Phone__c = :campaignNumber LIMIT 1];
        } catch (QueryException qe) {
            reply(campaignNumber, leadNumber, 'No Campaign configured. Sorry.');
            return;
        }

        // Create and insert a new Lead
        Lead lead = new Lead(LastName = 'From SMS',
            Company = 'From SMS',
            Email = leadEmail, 
            Phone = leadNumber);

        try {
            insert lead;
        } catch (DmlException dmle) {
            String message = (dmle.getDmlType(0) == StatusCode.INVALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS)
                ? leadEmail+' doesn\'t look like an email address. Please try again.'
                : 'An error occurred. Sorry.';
            reply(campaignNumber, leadNumber, message);
            return;
        }

        // Link the Lead to the Campaign
        insert new CampaignMember(CampaignId = campaign.Id, LeadId = lead.Id);

        // We're done - send an SMS 
        reply(campaignNumber, leadNumber, 'Thanks for registering. We\'ll send you a confirmation email!');

        // Send an email, recording it as an activity
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        mail.setTargetObjectId(lead.Id);
        mail.setSaveAsActivity(true);
        mail.setSenderDisplayName(campaign.Name);
        mail.setSubject('Welcome!');
        mail.setPlainTextBody('Thanks for registering!');
        Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
    }
}
```

What could be going wrong? How can I fix it? [Here's an unanswered Q with the same problem](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/178933/lost-our-visualforce-page-for-apex-controller-to-send-sms-via-twilio) (the Twilio debug part, anyway).

Comment: *Can someone please help?* is a yes/no question whose answer helps you not one bit. I tweaked your post to ask a more useful question and format the errors in a more standard way so it's easier to find for our frequent users.